# PHP - Passing JSON to Python script

Tags: php, python, json

I have this array in my PHP:

```
$coordinates[] = [
        1 => [
            'x' => 300,
            'y' => 200,
            'w' => 400,
            'h' => 500,
        ]
    ];

    $coordinates[] = [
        2 => [
            'x' => 350,
            'y' => 100,
            'w' => 400,
            'h' => 500,
        ]
 ];

//Convert the array to JSON
$json = json_encode($coordinates);

//Invoke the python script:
$process = new Process("python3 /MyFile.py {$json}");
$process->run();
```

Each array is a specific page, that have specific coordinates.

I want to send these to a Python script through the CLI. In my Python script, I fetch it like:

```
import sys
import json

COORDINATES_JSON = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else None
COORDINATES = json.loads(COORDINATES_JSON)
```

However, that gives me below error:

```
Error Output:
================
sh: sysctl: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyPyFile.py", line 5, in <module>
    COORDINATES = json.loads(COORDINATES_JSON)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is php code encoding json?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Ah sorry, forgot to include that! I have updated my question with the `$json` that is passed to the Python script.

Comment: Now add the code that invokes python script. I am 100% sure you do this wrong, without proper escaping and end up bitten by quotes, though.

Comment: There is nothing in your question that shows that you have even tried debugging your code. Have you?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Updated my question with how I am invoking my script

Comment: Exactly as I predicted. Here: https://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski - Thank you! I had no idea I had to do this. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `escapeshellarg($json)` as suggested in the comments.

```
// Invoke the python script:
$json = escapeshellarg($json);
$process = new Process("python3 /MyFile.py {$json}");
$process->run();
```

Or you could put the json in a file and retrieve it in python.

```
file_put_contents('json_file.json', $json);
```

You could also store your json in memory, the database or other means but I would suggest sticking with the first option above.